# Derivation of D-dimensional Laplacian in spherical coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry, physics, laplacian

I'm trying to derive the D-dimensional laplacian over Euclidean space for a function $f$ that is invariant under D-dimensional Euclidean rotations.

Specifically i'm trying to go from the equation

$$
\Delta_D \phi = U'(\phi)
$$

to the equation

$$
\frac{d^2\phi}{dr^2}+\frac{D-1}{r}\frac{d\phi}{dr} = U'(\phi)
$$

where $r = (x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+\dots+x_D^2)^{1/2}$. I'm a physicist and currently I don't have much knowledge about differential geometry and operators over manifolds, but still i wanted to know how, in a rigorous manner, to derive that equation under that change of coordinates.

Searching on the internet i found that the general form for the laplacian is given by the Laplace-Beltrami operator

$$
\Delta_D \phi= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\det g}}\partial_i\left(\sqrt{\det g}g^{ij}\partial_j\phi\right)
$$

but i don't know how the metric tensor is in the coordinates specified. I know that in Euclidian space is just a Kroneker delta, but what about spherical coordinates? 
On the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%E2%80%93Beltrami_operator#Examples) article gives the result right away without any explanation.

I'm really curious to see how to derive it. I didn't find any explanation with computation in my google search.

Comment: Have you seen this text : https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/bbm%3A978-1-4614-0706-5%2F1.pdf ? Besides, a little detail : Euclidian $\to$ Euclidean

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you're a physicist, I thought a variational derivation might be appealing. Consider the functional $$F[\phi]=\int \left[\frac12(\nabla \phi)^2+U(\phi)\right] dV.$$ Then the functional derivative is $$\frac{\delta}{\delta \phi}F[\rho]=\frac{\partial U}{\partial \phi}-\nabla^2 \phi =U'(\phi)-\Delta_D \phi,$$ so your first equation is equivalent to $\delta F[\phi]/\delta \phi=0$. But $\phi$ is a function of $r$ alone, so we can integrate out the irrelevant angular degrees of freedom to obtain $$F[\phi]=C_D\int \left[\frac12(\partial_r \phi)^2+U(\phi)\right] r^{D-1}dr$$ where $C_D$ is some $D$-dependent multiplicative constant. We may then compute the functional derivative once again as
$$\dfrac{\delta}{\delta \phi}F[\phi]=C_n \left[U'(\phi)r^{D-1}-\partial_r(r^{D-1}  \partial_r\phi)\right]=C_n r^{D-1}\left[U'(\phi)-\frac{D-1}{r}\frac{d\phi}{dr}-\frac{d^2\phi}{dr^2} \right].$$
For this variational derivative to vanish again, we must therefore have $$\Delta_D \phi = U'(\phi) = \frac{d^2\phi}{dr^2}+\frac{D-1}{r}\frac{d\phi}{dr}$$ which was the result to be derived.

Comment: I love this! Thank you so much. This way is much clearer to me. Maybe in the future i'll go in depth in the differential geometry way.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a longer derivation that requires mostly basic calculus.

The Laplacian is invariant under rotations.  Specifically, if $f:\mathbb R^n\rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ and $\nabla^2 f(x)\;=\alpha$, then $\nabla^2 g\;
(R^{-1} x)=\alpha$ where $R$ is any rotation matrix ($R^TR=I$ and $\det(R)=1$) and $g(x) := f(Rx)$.

Now suppose that $f:\mathbb R^n\rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ has the property that $f(x)= h(||x||)$ where $h:\mathbb [0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb R$, $h$ is twice differentiable, and $||x||=\sqrt{\sum_i x_i^2}.$

At $x$, we can form an orthonormal basis $\{x/||x||, v_2, v_3, \ldots v_{n-1}\}$.  Now
$$
\nabla^2 f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i^2}(x)
$$ 
and by invariance under rotation, we can use the basis  $\{x/||x||, v_2, v_3, \ldots v_{n-1}\}$ to get
\begin{equation}
(1)\quad\quad\nabla^2 f(x)= h''(||x||) + \sum_{i=2}^n p_i
\end{equation}
where $p_i:= k_i''(0)$ and $k_i(\epsilon) := f(x+\epsilon v_i)$.

The fact that $f$ only depends on the radius implies that all of the $k_i$ are the same and for $i=2, 3, \ldots n$, 
$$f(x+\epsilon v_i) = k_i(\epsilon) = k(\epsilon) = f(x+ \epsilon v_2)=h(\sqrt{||x||^2+\epsilon^2}).$$

Let $r=||x||$.  Using calculus, 
$$k'(\epsilon) = h'(\sqrt{r^2+\epsilon^2})\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{r^2+\epsilon^2}}, \quad \mathrm{and} $$
$$k''(\epsilon) = h''(\sqrt{r^2+\epsilon^2})\frac{\epsilon^2}{r^2+\epsilon^2} + h'(\sqrt{r^2+\epsilon^2})\frac{\sqrt{r^2+\epsilon^2} -\epsilon \frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{r^2+\epsilon^2}} }{r^2+\epsilon^2}.$$
Thus $p_i:= k''(0) = h''(r)\cdot 0 + h'(r)\frac{r}{r^2}=h'(r)/r$.  Applying this to equation (1) gives
$$
\nabla^2f(x)= h''(||x||) + \sum_{i=2}^n p_i =  h''(r) + (n-1)\frac{h'(r)}{r}.
$$

Comment: Yes, even this i can understand! Very straight forward, thanks